# How to get value of enums case?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, enums

I'm working with swift `enum`s. And my `enum` looks like this:

```
enum DataStructures<T> {
    case element(value: T)
    case elements(value: [T])
}
```

and I initialized `DataStructures` like this:

```
DataStructures.element(value: resultElement)
```

`resultElement` is of `ResultElement` type:

```
resultElement: ResultElement
```

My question is: Is there a way to extract `resultElement`'s value from enum's `case`, to get that object back after `DataStructures.element(value: resultElement)` has been passed to some method as a parameter for instance? Also that parameter looks like this:

```
data: DataStructures<ResultElement>
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use pattern matching:

```
if case .element(let value) = someParameter {
    print(value) // or do whatever you want with it
} else {
    // do some other thing in the case of the parameter not being .element
}
```

Comment: Thanks sir, that helped me to fix my problem.

Comment: @MattCodes if you think my answer answers your question, please consider accepting it by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 1):

```
enum DataStructures<T> {
    case element(value: T)
    case elements(value: [T])
}

let x = DataStructures<Int>.element(value: 5)

switch x {
case .element(let value):
    print(value) // 5
case .elements(let values):
    print(values)
}
```

Can refer you here (see the Associated Values section):
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Enumerations.html

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I wasn't familiar with pattern matching like Sweeper suggested it in answer bellow.